# Getting type of nested enum having only string?

Tags: c#, enums, runtime

What i'm trying to do is get `Type` of `enum` which is nested in `Class` having only name of that enumerator as string.

example:

```
public static class MyClassWithEnumNested
{
     public enum NestedEnum
     {
         SomeEnum1,
         SomeEnum2,
         SomeEnum3
     }
}
```

i need get

```
Type type = //what shall I write here?
Type type = Type.GetType("MyClassWithEnumNested.NestedEnum");//that doesn't work
```

Is there any way to get this `Type` in runtime?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
Type.GetType("MyClassWithEnumNested+NestedEnum");
```

Comment: I would be interested in a link to the documentation :)

Comment: @chiffre, sure, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx).

Comment: I think the namespace gotta figure in there too

Comment: This will work, assuming `MyClassWithEnumNested` is not in a namespace. It's not clear to me from the question that that's the case.

Comment: @svick, the question was about the nested type; I assume that the OP knows about the namespaces (but the `+` instead of the `.` for nested types is not intuitive).

Comment: @Lucero Thanks for link to the documentation :) Thats exacly what i needed :)